# What does "Reconversion" do in notepad?

Tags: windows, notepad, input-languages, ime

When I right click on Notepad, there come up options for right-to-left languages. But at the end exists an option "Reconversion". I have installed a Japanese LIP and it seems like I have got hold of the "Open IME" option above it. An inline change of characters from English to Japanese happens. From whatever I have read in official MSDN sources, it looks like "Reconversion" is related to it and is used to change the character chosen for the English source characters.

Now my question is, why is "Reconversion" always greyed out in notepad? To generate a list of characters, I simply typed a space before a list of characters popped down. Wasn't that the supposed function of "Reconversion"? If not, why is it really there in the list?

Answer (score 1):

Reconversion allows users who are typing in certain languages to convert back and forth between the phonetic spelling of a word (using the standard Western keyboard) and the character that represents the word. When a user types a phonetic representation of a word, a candidate list is displayed on the screen. The user can select the intended word or phrase from among several different possible representations in the candidate list, and the user's selection then replaces the phonetic representation in the document.

To get it working you have to add the languages and maybe keybord layouts in control panel.